# How to get IAP SKU code from google play console?

Tags: java, android

How can I get the SKU code from my google developer console for my in app purchase?

I did the following:

- Uploaded a alpha APK to google console.
- Created a new managed product for the app (IAP)

Google says it will be active when I release my app, however, how can I get the SKU for that item so I can add it in my app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SKU is basically the product ID.
In the Play Developer console, it will be found under Store Presence -> In App Products.

There is a table, where the first header item is Name/ID. The ID(SKU) of the product is what you are looking for. In the image below, the SKU will be **titi.cad**

The table is similar to this: 
[image: List of In-app products]

Comment: Thanks! So, this SKU and my public key should link purchases to me, correct?

Comment: @xFlare yes, they will

Comment: In the new and much worse redesign of the Play Console, it's available in Products > In-app products under 'Monetization' in the left sidebar.

Comment: Can I get list of SKUs dynamically ?